# Registry key as username and password

Tags: vb.net, registrykey

I have a small requirement, currently we are migrating an application from .net 2.0 to .net 4.6.2 framework. Here the problem is application login details such as username and password are given through registry key. Now we are unable to use the same registry key file.
When we tried to run the application, its showing the below error.

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.
Get the values from registry and then check if they are same as username and password provided by user.

**Note:** Some of your values may differ

```
Dim username = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Foresight\identity\ASPNET_SETREG", "username", Nothing))
Dim password = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Foresight\identity\ASPNET_SETREG", "password", Nothing))
```